# OSGi Manifest is empty

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bundle

I'm trying to create a service, and then put it to felix OSGi container. I try to do this with `maven-bundle-plugin`. After `mvn clean install` package is installed, also in `target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.INF` i get filled file, but in `jar` Manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: szymon.nowak
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_77`
```

and that's how it should look:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1471013023955
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_77
Built-By: szymon.nowak
Bundle-Activator: com.cognifide.activators.HelloWorldActivator
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Hello World Bundle - service
Bundle-SymbolicName: OSGi Hello World Service
Bundle-Vendor: Szymon Nowak
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: com.cognifide.service.first;version="1.0.0"
Import-Package: com.cognifide.service.first,org.osgi.framework;version="
 [1.5,2)"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))"
Tool: Bnd-3.2.0.201605172007
```

In fact, felix register that file, but they're not working, since ther's no Export-package or Activator set. That's how my plugin defiinition in pom looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>bundle-manifest</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>manifest</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>OSGi Hello World Service</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Export-Package>com.cognifide.service.first</Export-Package>
            <Bundle-Activator>com.cognifide.activators.HelloWorldActivator</Bundle-Activator>
            <Bundle-Name>Hello World Bundle - service</Bundle-Name>
            <Bundle-Vendor>Szymon Nowak</Bundle-Vendor>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

EDIT.

I build my project with `mvn clean install`. Maybe i should use some phase of that plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the executions section. I think what you have now tells the maven-bundle-plugin to only create the Manifest but not to package it.

Also make sure you have

```
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
```

Comment: `executions` generates a good `Manifest` in `target/classes/META-INF`. After removing it, it's still not create good `Manifest` in my jar file.